# "Illegal character in path" .net MVC4 SignalR version 1.1.4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I am not sure when this is happening but it started out of no where, and happens during the return of any view from an action method of a controller. This is running on Visual studio, here is the error:

```
   System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
   at System.Web.Configuration.UserMapPath.GetPhysicalPathForPath(String path, VirtualDirectoryMapping mapping)
   at System.Web.Configuration.UserMapPath.GetPathConfigFilename(String siteID, VirtualPath path, String& directory, String& baseName)
   at System.Web.Configuration.UserMapPath.MapPath(String siteID, String path)
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPathActual(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitNull)
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPathInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitNull)
   at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetPhysicalPath(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(String configPath)
   at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetVirtualPathData(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitPathsOutsideApp)
   at System.Web.HttpContext.GetFilePathData()
   at System.Web.HttpContext.GetConfigurationPathData()
   at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetConfig(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpContext.get_ImpersonationToken()
   at System.Web.ClientImpersonationContext.Start(HttpContext context, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Web.ThreadContext.SetImpersonationContext()
   at System.Web.ThreadContext.AssociateWithCurrentThread(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
```

And this is my error catching findings:

```
MvcApplication: 08:59:37,017 [40] ERROR - Requested url: /function () {"use strict"; _pageLoaded = true; }
MvcApplication: 08:59:37,033 [40] ERROR - Requested Path: /function () {"use strict"; _pageLoaded = true; }
```

It looks like this is coming from a jquery library possibly. I am using version 3.1.1

What is the best way to handle this, and why would it suddenly start happening?  I did install SignalR Api, but there were not any apparent issues right away. I am also using Boostrap as well in my MVC4 application with .net 4.0

*Update*, hmm I removed my SignalR script bundle, and it resolved the issue. So it has something to do with SignalR scripts, version 1.1.4

*Update2*, tried updating to a later version of SignalR (version 1.2.2) that still supports .net framework 4.0 and still getting the same issues. I think this version is the latest to support 4.0, this is what I saw and gathered from NUGET gallery.

Comment: .NET Framework 4 stopped being supported more than a year ago: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/

Comment: Tell that to my company. I have tried to push for newer versions of visual studio. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Switching to jquery.signalR-1.2.2.min.js from jquery.signalR-1.2.2.js seemed to resolve this issue.</strike>

Actually, it only worked because the bundle was ignoring the .min.js files and not adding it at all. Gave the illusion it was working. Found that out and then found the real culprit.

I forgot to add the maphubs,

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
```